# Memory buffer in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, command-line

I have recently finished a script that will ask for a hostname and automatically take the argument of the `function` and `ssh` into one of my work servers.

Here is a copy of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Provide hostname: "
read host

createSSHFunction()
{
    arg1=$1
    ssh $host
}
createSSHFunction $host

while((1)); do ~/sshScript.sh; done
```

What I notice though is say I want to `ssh` into one of the servers and I got disconnected, by instinct I will press the Up arrow key to redisplay the same argument I put in the last time. Here is an example of that:

```
    Provide hostname:
    crf-alpha
    support@localhost's password:
    Last login: Thu Jul 24 12:16:33 2014 from localhost
    [support@crf-alpha ~]$
Connection to localhost closed.
Provide hostname:
^[[A
```

Is there such a way to code in my current script where it will buffer anything I type last? So for example i `ssh` into the crf-alpha and I get disconnected. My script will run again prompting me to enter a hostname, I would like it so that if I press the Up arrow key, the last input I entered will re-display, so in this case crf-alpha rather than the weird symbol I always get.

Comment: You could try using `rlwrap`

Comment: Zsh might be able to. But then zsh could cook breakfast and make your bed if you try hard enough. But this is not something bash can do itself.

Comment: Oh okay, I can't install anything my servers don't have on it, since I don't have `sudo` access. I figured there may be something built-in that I can use.

Comment: @user000001 you should test that and post it as an answer.

Comment: It's almost possible to have bash do this, but not quite. `read` does have a `-e` argument which uses the readline library, but there's no way to get it to use an alternative history buffer.

Comment: I will give the `rlwrap` and/or the `-e` argument in `read` a try when I get freed up. Its no big deal if it's not possible without downloading an additional package/software. This is more of a convenience for me

Comment: @derobert Tested with OP's script and posted an answer.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what this script is providing you over `ssh hostname`... If you were doing that, then the normal bash history stuff would work. I presume the script actually does (or will do) more than you've shown, but maybe there is a way to do that, but still keep bash's history?

Comment: @derobert I built a tmux program that will automatically call this script so that I can use 3 screens to call this script in an endless loop. It saves me keystrokes, thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can install the `rlwrap` utility, then it is as simple as doing

```
rlwrap ./yourscript.sh
```

This will allow you to use the up and down array keys to browse through history, as well as the right and left arrow keys for editing the current command, for programs that do not support it already.

Comment: I can't install anything, unfortunately. I don't have sudo access to the server

Comment: @ryekayo you do not need root access to install things. You can install programs in, e.g., $HOME/bin.

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I'm free

Comment: @ryekayo BTW: rlwrap runs on the local machine, not the remote ones, you don't need to install anything on the remote machines.